# Add many to many relation without fetching child entity from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have Book and Author entities with many to many relation and I am trying to save the relation (a record in junction table) with Database first approach.

I would like to start with my working version of code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(BookViewModel bookv)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<AuthorViewModel, Author>();
            List<Author> authors = Mapper.Map<List<AuthorViewModel>, List<Author>>
(bookv.Authors.ToList());
//remove authors from book object to avoid multiple entities with same key error
           bookv.Authors.Clear();
            Mapper.CreateMap< BookViewModel,Book>();
            Book  book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel,Book>(bookv);

            db.Books.Attach(book);          
            book.Authors.Clear();
            foreach (Author a in authors)
            {
                //Fetch Author and add relation to book object
                book.Authors.Add(db.Authors.Single(at=>at.AuthorId==a.AuthorId));
            }

            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(book, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

In above code, I am fetching Author object (record) from database to add relation with book object. Whereas,**I am not fetching Book object from database but attaching it to the context. Can't I do something similar with Author objects?**

I have tried to do this with this code but it first adds new records to Author table and adds relation with book and newly created (unwanted) authors:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(BookViewModel bookv)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<AuthorViewModel, Author>();
        List<Author> authors = Mapper.Map<List<AuthorViewModel>, List<Author>>(bookv.Authors.ToList());
    //   bookv.Authors.Clear();
        Mapper.CreateMap< BookViewModel,Book>();
        Book  book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel,Book>(bookv);

        foreach (Author a in book.Authors)
        {
            db.Authors.Attach(a);
        }

        db.Books.Attach(book);

        foreach (Author a in authors)
        {
            book.Authors.Add(a);
        }
     db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(book, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(BookViewModel bookv)
        {
            //create maps
            Mapper.CreateMap<AuthorViewModel, Author>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<BookViewModel, Book>();

            //convert view objects to model objects
            Book book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(bookv);
            List<Author> authors = Mapper.Map<List<AuthorViewModel>, List<Author>>   (bookv.Authors.ToList());

            book.Authors.Clear();
            db.Books.Attach(book);


            foreach (Author a in authors) { db.Authors.Attach(a); }

            book.Authors.Clear();

            foreach (Author a in authors) { book.Authors.Add(a); }

            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(book, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `db.Books.Attach(book)` before the `db.Authors.Attach(a)` loop?

Also, have you tried adding the book to the authors? Like `a.Books.Add(book);` instead?

iow,

```
db.Books.Attach(book);
foreach (Author a in book.Authors)
{
    db.Authors.Attach(a);
    a.Books.Add(book);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thedeeno . But it didn't do anything at all. No errors and duplicates.

Comment: I changed the code to this and its working fine. Attaching Book before Author was the key thing to do.
`db.Books.Attach(book);
          
         foreach (Author a in authors)
                {
                    db.Authors.Attach(a);
                }

      book.Authors.Clear();

                foreach (Author a in authors)
                {
                    book.Authors.Add(a);
               
                }`