# Entity Framework 3.5 Many-to-Many update issue

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Dear StackOverflow community,

I have a problem to update a many-to-many relationship in EF 3.5:

But first of all, here you can see my Tables:

```
Table "Message":

ID, int (primary key)
Message, string

Table "DisplayDestinations":

ID, int (primary key)
Destination, string

My DisplayDestinations are:

ID;Destination:

1;PC
2;Mobile
3;Printer
4;PDF
```

I think you can imagine that a "Message" can have multiple DisplayDestinations.

I can insert and delete "Messages" or single "DisplayDestinations". But if I want to update them, I get an error.

EF 3.5 want to create a new "DisplayDestinations" but I don't have any line of code to do this...

Here is my update method. It could be solved inconveniently but why can't I update this:

```
List<DisplayDestinations> CorrectMDfromMDs = new List<DisplayDestinations>(); // Holds the real DisplayDestinations with the right ID and Destination
      foreach (Message item in Messages)
      {
        // Get all DisplayDestinations with the EntityState Added or Modified to know which to add.
        var ChangedMDs = item.DisplayDestinations.Where(x => x.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added || x.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (MD md in ChangedMDs)
        {
          CorrectMDfromMDs.Add(DBService.GetMDs().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == md.ID));

        }

        // delete the DisplayDestinations from the Message which modified or added state, because they aren't the right from my DisplayDestinations
        while (ChangedMDs.Count() > 0)
        {
          item.MDs.Remove(ChangedMDs.ElementAt(0));
        }

        // Add the right DisplayDestinations to the Message
        foreach (var md in CorrectMDfromMDs)
        {
          item.MDs.Add(md);
        }

        CorrectMDfromMDs.Clear();
      }
      DBService.SaveChanges();
```

After that, I get an exception that Destination from DisplayDestinations cannot be NULL. I think EF 3.5 tries to add an new DisplayDestination into DisplayDestinations but why?

I have tried this [Insert/Update Many to Many Entity Framework . How do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253165/insert-update-many-to-many-entity-framework-how-do-i-do-it) but without success.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your calling FirstOrDefault on ( x => x.ID == md.ID )

I'm guessing that the ones that are added **EntityState.Added** don't exist in the DB yet.
and they are the ones which return the null (default value) from your Linq expression.

and if it is not redundant to explain CorrectMDfromMDs now has some Null items in it.

Comment: Hey eran otzap, thanks for your answer but I think you are wrong. Because the FirstOrDefault returns null when nothing matches. And the other loops aren't iterate then because they are null. Or Do I get you wrong? What would you suggest to solve this?

Comment: 1) you select all Added and Modified .
2) U run over them asking .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == md.ID) .
3) The ones who were added don't exit in the DB so they are not found and Linq return a null value for you.
4) Then you place that null in CorrectMDfromMDs.