# Junction Table in ASP .NET code first approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, junction-table

I am creating a junction table between Identity User and a Game table. This table is called UserGame and has two foreign keys (UserID, GameID) and one additional field to store the score.

```
public class UserGame
{
    [Key]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

My confusion lies with creating a new UserGame record. How would I go about doing this and is my approach correct?

Update (This worked):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitScore(int gameID, int score)
    {
        var playerRecord = new UserGame();

        playerRecord.ApplicationUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        playerRecord.GameID = gameID;
        playerRecord.Score = score;

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `ApplicationUserId` and `GameId` must have a `[Key, Column(Order = 0)]` attribute. Just set the first to Order 0 and the other to 1.

```
public class UserGame
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [Key, Colum(Order = 1)]
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have the choice to add new record, go through nav property from `Game` or `ApplicationUser` or directly with your `UserGame` class.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still a little lost on adding a new record. I have chosen to go directly with my UserGame class. I created a new UserGame object in my controller. I can assign the gameID and score. I'm wondering if this approach is correct: Retrieve the current user signed in through the User.Identity.GetUserID()  and set this as the ApplicationuserID field.

Comment: Yup, this is a way to go, to add the newly UserGame entity, add it to your context. You should have it as DbSet in your DbContext right ?

Comment: It's working now, could not find this approach anywhere. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

[Example of configuring many-to-many relationship in entity framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

[Examle of inserting related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253165/insert-update-many-to-many-entity-framework-how-do-i-do-it)

A couple of tips: 
I wouldn't declare a primary key in the junction entity as junctions are usually defined by composite keys.
Keep in mind that dbcontext.SaveChanges() will look for child entities and save those as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my issue with that example is storing the additional field 'Score'. Should this be in the Game class?