# How join related data from many to many relationship between two tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables like this:

```
public partial class Major
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Salon> Salons { get; set; }
}

public class Salon
{
       public int Id { set; get; }
       public string Title { set; get; }
       public ICollection<Salon> Salons { get; set; }
}
```

In the table `Major`, I have data like this:

```
Id  Name
-----------------
1   basketball
2   vollyball
```

and my problem is when I am adding a new record to the `Salon` table with related data of `basketball` and `volleyball`; these two records have been added as new records to the `Major` table when they already existed...

Comment: ***SHOW US THE CODE!*** We cannot possibly help you if you only talk about it - **SHOW IT!** - after all, we cannot read your screen, nor your mind - you need to show us, so that we have any chance of helping you!

Comment: This has been asked before, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4253165/861716.